# FIFO Queue improvement for C#

Tags: c#, queue, fifo

hi i am working on an assignment and i should implement a queue which handles jobs waiting to be processed (producer-consumer problem). I have to develop a better queue that works more efficiently than the FIFO queue. There are parameters that describe the waiting time before the starvation occurs, the time they need to process after the queue is over for them. consumers come at a specified time, can wait for specified time and they take some time to execute whatever they wanna do when their turn has come. can you help me with a better queue rather than FIFO method?

Comment: Have you tried googling for other implementations? There are lots of different implementations, with examples and explanations out there. This isn't spark notes or a free homework sort of website. Start with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are trying to solve different problems at the same time, if you want to improve the performance of the regular queue, you can implement a queue based on a priority of the elements(a heap) if you want to maintain the priority of the regular queue you can put a priority based on an integer, increasing that number every time you add an element into the heap.

Here I am attaching the first link that I found on google for
[Priority queue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126751/Priority-queue-in-C-with-the-help-of-heap-data-str). The order of the insertion is O(log n) if you use a [Binary Heap](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_heap/Insertion)

Now if you want to implement that queue allowing concurrency, you need to isolate the common resource(for example the basic structure where the heap store the elements).

[Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Pulse_Producer_Consumer_Queue) is a good reference to see how producer-consumer works with the concurrency.

And here are all the classes that you can use to implement the concurrency for producer-consumer [Concurrency sheet](http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/csharp-concurrency-cheat-sheet/)

I am adding an example with one of those Types

```
 //BlockingCollection with a fix number of Products to put, it works with 10 items max on the collection
    class Program
    {
        private static int counter = 1;
        private static BlockingCollection<Product> products =
            new BlockingCollection<Product>(10);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //three producers
            Task.Run(() => Producer());
            Task.Run(() => Producer());
            Task.Run(() => Producer());

            Task.Run(() => Consumer());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Producer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var product = new Product()
                {
                    Number = counter,
                    Name = "Product " + counter++
                };

                //Adding one element
                Console.WriteLine("Producing: " + product);
                products.Add(product);

                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        static void Consumer()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //wait until exist one element
                if (products.Count == 0)
                    continue;

                var product = products.Take();
                Console.WriteLine("Consuming: " + product);

                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
```